# Creating prepopulated aspx files with c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, file, directory

My objective is to write a program that can create folders and within those folders create Default.aspx pages. The Default.aspx pages must read information from the database to populate the page using their containing folder name as a parameter to call the database.

Create the folders is the easy part, but I'm not sure how to go about writing information to .aspx files.

The goal of this project is so a real estate company can create pages for featured properties (through a cms), each featured property getting it's own folder/page.

Any feedback would be great.
-Aaron

Comment: Curious:why not provide them with a form to edit the database and just serve the content directly from the db? Urls don't have to map to a real file. Have a look at MVC.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than physically creating the .aspx files, I think it makes more sense to have 1 .aspx file, which is passed querystring values to return different content from the CMS, depending on its value.

Furthermore, you could use URL Rewriting to make the file appear as if its in a physical location, within a folder.

For example:

/Property.aspx?agent=EstateAgent1&name=Property1

Can be rewritten to:

/EstateAgent/Property1.aspx

---

If you *have* to generate folders and files, I'd recommend simply generating HTML files, as theres no need for the file to be dynamic, or ran at the server

Comment: Thanks, I think URL Rewriting would work just fine. I haven't had to use it before but it appears that this is a solution.
Thanks again,
-Aaron

Answer (score 0):

I would create a template ASPX page, and copy that template into the new folders. Within the template, define the layout and add all of the necessary controls for displaying the data. Doing it this way, you can change your template as needed for changes, and after the template is copied to the folder you can customize it as needed.

I would be remiss not to warn you that this approach will be very difficult to maintain though. Unless there is some requirement I'm unaware of, I don't know why this approach would be favorable.

Hope this helps.